# Multiple subnets on multiple virtual interfaces with one physical interface

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a Ubuntu pc with one interface -- `eth0` -- which is connected to an unmanaged switch which is linked to two subnets: `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24`. I want to have two virtual interfaces with different MAC's on Ubuntu pc to connect to both the subnets (each virtual interface is connected to a different subnet). I do not want an alias (eth0:0), because I also want to add default gateways (192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1) of both subnets. What I want is something like another dumb virtual switch inside Ubuntu pc to which I can add two or more virtual interfaces. I tried the [answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/223601/multiple-mac-addresses-on-one-physical-network-interface-linux), but when I ping the ip of the virtual interface I get the MAC of eth0. Also I created a bridge and gave different ips representing different subnets to `br0` and `eth0`, but that too didn't work. I have tried every possible howto and I have also googled for months on the issue: the only solution seems to be to buy another network card and plug both to my unmanaged switch.

Comment: This would be really easy if you had a managed switch with VLAN support.

Comment: Also, you cannot have multiple default gateways. It's called a "default" gateway for a reason. How would the system know which to use if there were more than one of them?

Comment: @larsks If I have two links from different ISP's who provide me /29 subnets each, would I be able to have seprate virtual interfaces for each of the IP's (all 10 ip's from both ISP's) with only a physical connection to a managed switch?

Comment: If you have a switch with VLAN support, then you can trunk multiple layer 2 networks over a single physical cable.  You create multiple VLAN interfaces on your Linux that will act to most intents and purposes like separate physical interfaces.  Take a look at [this document](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7268) and see if it makes sense.